# Run bat file using Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I have a batch file FolderWatcher.bat.

And I created a task with task scheduler in Windows 7. I need to run it in a specific time(once) and should not stop until the user wants it to stop. (Start once and should run for days and days.)
UAC is off and I am Admin.

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: This post should be migrated to Superuser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722178.aspx

> A task's settings are displayed on the Settings tab of the Task Properties or Create Task dialog box. The following list contains the descriptions of task settings.
>
> **Stop the task if it runs longer than: time period**
>
> - This setting allows you to limit the amount of time a task is allowed to run. Use this setting to limit tasks that might take a long period of time to execute, causing an inconvenience to the user.

Just uncheck this setting and you should be good.